# Div not expanding its height to variable iframe height

Tags: html, css

A very simple concept is giving me a very complex headache!

I have a roster that is being generated externally. The height of it always changes from day to day as it's updated. I'm calling that roster with an iframe inside of a div called roster.

Every time I refresh the page to look at the results, the div refuses to expand and inherit the height of the iframe (whatever it happens to be that day).

The code I'm using for the div in the CSS table is:

```css
#roster {
  width: 65%;
  height: auto;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 5px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  background-color: #000000;
}
```

And the iframe tag in the HTML file looks like:

```html
<iframe id="classRoster" src="http://example.com/roster.php" scrolling="no" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" frameborder="0" vspace="0" hspace="0" style="overflow:visible; width:100%; height:100%; display:block"></iframe>
```

The roster Div expands about maybe one third of the way down the length of the iframe and then it stops/closes/cuts off. Anyone have any suggestions how I can force it to keep going and cut off a few pixels after the iframe is actually finished?

Thanks very much in advance :)

Comment: I think the problem happens when you set the child height to 100% and the parent height to auto.

Comment: Do you have any tips on how I would remedy that? I could keep the parent set to auto but I'd never have any clue how big the child is because the iframe's data (the roster itself) can change from day to day.

Comment: I don't understand one thing sorry. But #roster is inside or outside iframe?